# Is it safe to alloc a NSThread and then initWithTarget the thread multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

I have a custom patch for Quartz Composer that is a multicast receiver.  It fires up a NSThread for the daemon and then restarts it when the user changes the multicast address or port number.

When the patch starts I do the following to launch a new thread.

```
daemonThread = [NSThread alloc];
```

Then, every time I start or restart the thread I reinitialize it like:

```
[daemonThread initWithTarget:multicastDaemon selector:@selector(doWorkWithDelegate:) object:self];
[daemonThread start];
```

Of course, I terminate the thread each time before I restart it.  I'm not using garbage collection, and I do release the daemonThread when the patch exits.

My concern is that I'm not sure what happens when I re-initialize this thread over and over like that.   I've noticed that Instruments tells me I'm leaking an NSThread and a autoreleasepool, which I suspect may be my pool from the daemon thread.  I can see that these numbers increment each time I restart the process, but I'm not familiar enough with Instruments to know what it's telling me.

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to call any `init...` method on any object that has already been initialized. This includes NSThread.

Comment: What if the thread has exited?  I've done this such that the thread has a delegate with a didFinish type of method that is called just before a usleep then exit. That method sets a flag via ivar that says the thread is dead. Then, the next frame sees that the frame is dead and inits a daemonThread like you see above.  Is that safe?  I understand that a NSThread can't be restarted, which is why I ended up doing this.  If it's not safe, what are safe alternatives?

Comment: @Adam it is never safe to invoke an initializer multiple times on a single object. period.

Comment: The safe alternative is to allocate a new NSThread.  You don't know what resources NSThread might be allocating under the covers, that it only releases in `dealloc`, and thus leaks if you init it twice.  Also you might screw up ARC if you're using it.  "[It is undefined behavior for a program to cause two or more calls to init methods on the same object, except that each init method invocation may perform at most one delegate init call.](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family.semantics.init)"

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I've moved daemonThread from being an ivar, to just being a local variable.  I created a new local variable to point to daemonThread, so that I can still reference him to release him.  That got rid of the NSThread leak.  Then, I still had the nsautoreleasepool leak.  I noticed my [NSThread exit] in daemonThread was inside my autorelease pool, so I move it outside the pool.  That did it.  No more leaks!